# Failed to create depth stencil in DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

i have the following code:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
memset(&descDepth, 0, sizeof(descDepth));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
hr = g_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, nullptr, &g_depthStencil);
```

and `invalid argument` error. I really don't know what's the problem. I used this code before and everything worked fine.

Comment: Try enabling the debug layer. It should give you a more detailed description of the call failed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584.aspx

Comment: maybe try a different number for `SampleDesc.Count`. Also, how did you define `g_depthStencil`?

Comment: @rashmatash `ID3D11Texture2D *`

Comment: @RossRidge i have enabled the debug layer. But where i can find a log file?

Comment: You need to run it under a debugger to see the debug messages.

Comment: @RossRidge do you mean something like Unity Editor?

Comment: I think the answer is no, but I'm not familiar with Unity. The compiler you're using should come with a debugger. Visual Studio has one integrated into the IDE. MinGW GCC comes with the GDB command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you turned the debug layer on at the device creation, you should find in the log that `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` is not a texture format, You need to use `DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS` for the texture and the other one for the depth stencil view.

Comment: I am using `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` and everything works fine now. It failed because height was zero.